# How to autoupdate vimgrep search result in quickfix window?

Tags: vim

How to autoupdate search vimgrep results from quickfix window after file is autoudpated due to change?

I use :vim/pattern/% to search and put result in quickfix window.

Comment: rerun the command after the file was updated.

Comment: @kent, Thanks Kent. That's what I am doing currently, I want to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do `<up>` on the command line with a prefix of `:vimgrep` to make searching history easier. You may also want to check out `q:` and the use `?`/`/` to search for the command to re-execute.

Assuming the quickfix title is set correctly, you can use following the command:

```
:execute get(getqflist({'title':1}), 'title')
```

This however I am not certain this will work with all `:grep`/`:make` commands. You also need a newer Vim version to get the Quckfix list title (Vim 8+ I think).

If you find yourself doing this often you may want to bind a mapping or command.

```
command! -nargs=0 -bar QFRefresh execute get(getqflist({'title':1}), 'title')
```

Now how to add do this automatically? We can use `FileChangedShellPost` autocmd to run our `QFRefresh` command once a file change has been detected. Add the following to you `vimrc` file:

```
augroup QFRefresh
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileChangedShellPost * if get(b:, 'qfrefresh_auto', 0) | QFRefresh | endif
augroup END

command! -nargs=0 -bar QFAutoRefreshToggle let b:qfrefresh_auto = !get(b:, 'qfrefresh_auto', 0) | echo b:qfrefresh_auto ? 'Auto Refresh' : 'No Auto Refresh'
```

Now you can use `:QFAutoRefreshToggle` to toggle refreshing a file.

Note: As stated before `QFRefresh` uses the quickfix's title to get the quickfix command. If the title is not set correctly a refresh may not work correctly. Also I am not sure what guarantees Vim has on triggering `FileChangedShellPost`. You can force a check via `:checktime` command.

For more help see:

```
:h getqflist()
:h :execute
:h :get
:h q:
:h cmdwin
:h c_Up
:h FileChangedShellPost
:h :checktime
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I am not sure, how your answer automatically refreshes vimgrep search list.  I have a log file open and I have vimgreped a search pattern. When new entries are logged in the log file, vim auto load feature reloads the file. but the vimgrep window stays the same. I have to manually re-run vimgrep, I don't want to do that. After reload, I want vimgrep window to be refreshed as if I have run vimgrep command again.